# Detect the Paste Operation of an Image on UITextView. iOS | Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am working on a chat application. I'm able to copy and paste simple string into the textview. I want to detect when the user is trying to paste the image. I don't want to use `UITextPasteDelegate` as I'm also customising the text styles in `shouldChangeCharater(_:,:)` `Delegate`. I've tried creating a subclass of `UITextView` to `override` the `Paste(sender: Any?)` method but no solution amongst these suits my requirement. Is there any way to detect the same ?

Comment: Found any solution yet ?